# What is the .Rd encoding for @?

Tags: r, latex, rd

I'm trying to include some notes on LaTeX preamble requirements that will be needed to make certain options available in a package.  I need to get the following to render correctly in the `.Rd` file, but I consistently get the error

> Error: Failure in roxygen block beginning sprinkle.R:1 Mismatched
>   braces:

The offending section of (roxygen tagged) code is below

```
#' \tabular{ll}{
#'   Sprinkle \tab LaTeX Package(s) \cr
#'   \code{font_color} \tab \code{\\usepackage[dvipsnames]\{xcolor\}} \cr
#'   \code{bg, bg_pattern} \tab \code{\\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]\{xcolor\}} \cr
#'   \code{border_style} \tab  \code{\\usepackage\{amssymb\}} \cr
#'   \\ \\ (with vertical dashed lines) \tab \\usepackage\{graphicx\} \cr
#'   \\ \\ \tab \code{\\makeatletter} \cr
#'   \\ \\ \tab \code{\\newcommand*\vdashline\{\\rotatebox[origin=c]\{90\}\{\$\\dabar@\\dabar@\\dabar@\$\}\}} \cr
#' }
```

As soon as I take out the `@` symbols, it works fine.  How does one go about writing `@` in R help files?

Comment: IIRC you escape `@` via `@@`

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought to include roxygen in my search terms.